# Why does my button URL open natively in one org but in the built-in browser in another?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, quickaction

I have a quick action button on my Lead object which opens a flow, when pressing the button on Salesforce1 via the scratch org, the flow opens in the app appearing optimised and fit to the screen, however when I load the same button when logged into my sandbox (on the same phone), the button redirects to the inbuilt browser which loads the flow. The flow page loads as if its on a desktop and is quite small and needs scrolling to see all the text.

Why is the behaviour different?

I have checked and both button have the following settings:
Behaviour: Display in existing window with sidebar
URL: /flow/(flow_name)

Comment: Check if the Salesforce1 app is the same version in both environments. Sometimes, app updates can change how certain features behave. There might be configuration differences between your scratch org and your sandbox. Check if there are any Salesforce1-specific settings that differ.

Comment: How would I find this information? Its the same app being loaded on the same phone between different orgs.

Comment: start by logging into Salesforce on a desktop and accessing the Setup area in both orgs. Compare the Salesforce org versions under "Company Information" to ensure they are on the same release. Next, review Salesforce1 or mobile-related settings, potentially located in the Mobile Administration section, to spot any configuration differences. Also, check that the user profiles and permission sets in both orgs grant similar access, particularly for mobile and flow execution. Finally, confirm that the flow settings, with a focus on mobile optimization and display, are consistent across both orgs.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com I've looked and can't find any settings that are different. Do you have any particular setting that will tweak optimised views?

Comment: It might also be checking the Flow settings to ensure that it is running in Lightning Experience (or not) in both orgs.

Comment: Check that the Lightning pages associated with your flow, especially those on the Lead object, are optimized for mobile viewing. Sometimes, specific components or layout adjustments are needed for optimal display in Salesforce1.If your flow or any related process involves Visualforce pages, check their settings. Mobile optimization for Visualforce pages requires specific tags and design considerations. Within Salesforce1, there might be specific app settings that can impact how pages are displayed. Look for options related to page rendering or compatibility modes.